# Google chrome : text file auto wrap

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-frame

Google chrome seems to auto wrap the contents of a text file whn i open it. I am opening a link from my chrome extension whose response is a text file. When I open the same link in firefox, it opens with all the spacing and tab-space preserved. But that is not the case when U open it in chrome. It just auto wraps all its contents. Is there a way to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Is this extension related? Or you are just trying to do it manually?

Comment: It doesnt work either way.. If I have a text file which i manually write with tabs and spaces, I seem to loose them whn i open it in chrome.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google do not yet provide an option to switch between the described word wrapping and scrolling. A [feature request](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=117ad24e11bafe74&hl=en) is pending.